# QUERY function SELECT Col if it matches A2:A50 in source

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I'm trying to make a query function where I need to import data that matches a cell. A1 from the query needs to match col3 B1 from the spreadsheet, then A2 needs to match B2 and so on and so forth. Each cell from the query needs to match that respective cell in the working spreadsheet.

For example, I have

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1DLwAe8zdKikSmFt9grr-Hu2rPNbp6GmfhmbTq2hT-0s","'Current Clients'!A4:D"),"SELECT Col4 WHERE Col3 CONTAINS 'D2:D'",1)
```

It only brings the title of the column but the rest is blank, no data is popping up.

Because of business purposes I can't share my spreadsheet.

Comment: The string is constant, so you need to build it from multiple cells with concatenation

Comment: It is unclear whether you want to *filter* the imported data so that it only shows rows where Col3 matches at least one of the values in column D irrespective of row order in column D, or if you want to do a *lookup* where imported data is placed into the specific rows where the search key in column D matches an imported data row. To best get help, please share a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=query( 
  importrange("1DLwAe8zdKikSmFt9grr-Hu2rPNbp6GmfhmbTq2hT-0s", "Current Clients!A4:D"), 
  "select Col4 where '" & textjoin("|", true, D2:D) & "' contains Col3", 
  1 
)
```

Comment: Hi @doubleunary I just tried it and I get #VALUE Text result of JOIN is longer than the limit of 50000 characters. This is what i did





=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1DLwAe8zdKikSmFt9grr-Hu2rPNbp6GmfhmbTq2hT-0s","'Current Clients'!A4:D"),"SELECT Col4 WHERE '" & join("|", D2:D) & "' contains Col3",1)

Comment: The error indicates that your sheet must be quite tall. You may want to delete any unneeded blank rows at the bottom. Will edit the answer to work around the issue in any case.